# Gathering system activity information

Tags: objective-c, c, macos

Using Objective-C\C language I need to gather system activity information (like in Activity Monitor: CPU\Memory usage, network activity and so on). Please, tell me, what facilities (maybe there are some frameworks) I can use for this.
Will be great, if you point me to some article or guide, which describes 'what' and 'why'. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Makes me think of the `top` command, which supplies about all info.  The source code `libtop.c` should be easy to find. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077593/get-cpu-usage-for-process-by-pid-top-source-code) one link to get you started.