# Java ProcessHandle.Info.totalCpuDuration() returning very little data

Tags: java, time, process, cpu

When does the '`Optional<Duration> totalCpuDuration();`' method of `ProcessHandle.Info` return information?

I've tried with and without sudo, doesn't seem to make much difference; either way only the current process returns non-empty value. The documentation does not say much.

What stops the JVM stdlib running under sudo (on MacOS or Linux) from getting that information? Is it just not implemented? Would getting that info be too slow?

Comment: On my machine, `totalCpuDuration` is filled for every process (other fields are not). In general, there's nothing you can do, it's a permissions thing. You could query the processes in a OS-dependent manner if you really need to. I'm using Linux with OpenJDK 15, FWIW.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Yes, this work on Linux. So still very useful there. I checked the source, it's simply not implemented on MacOS, see answer.

Comment: FWIW, `java.lang.ProcessHandle.Info.totalCpuDuration()` returns a sadly empty `Optional` with `openjdk version "17.0.3"` on Fedora 36.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with permissions, at least on MacOS: it's just not implemented (as of May 2021).

For linux, the code seems to read the cpu time via the proc fs for all processes, or at least try to, permissions might apply.

For MacOS, it only reads info for the current process. It's hardcoded: `if (pid == getpid()) { ... }`; no attempt is made to get this info from other processes.

---

MacOS:

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk15u/blob/master/src/java.base/macosx/native/libjava/ProcessHandleImpl_macosx.c

Linux:

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk15u/blob/master/src/java.base/linux/native/libjava/ProcessHandleImpl_linux.c

---

And here's an answer with some code to implement a workaround with Java and shell exec:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36381244/336356

Answer (score -1):

An alternative way of getting Total CPU Duration of your process is this

```
ProcessHandle processHandle = ProcessHandle.of(<system pid>).get();
ProcessHandle.Info processInfo = processHandle.info();
long timeDiff = Instant.now().getEpochSecond() - processInfo.startInstant().get().getEpochSecond();
```

This works for any process that user has access to, not just current process.

Comment: I should have been clearer perhaps, I am interested in finding out the CPU load of processes. I believe the code you've posted gives us the wall-clock time, not the *CPU* duration/usage.

Comment: Ok then try this for a running process:
`processInfo.totalCpuDuration​().get().toMillis()`

Comment: Maybe my question is unclear. totalCpuDuration() returns Optional 'empty' for most processes. That's the problem: it doesn't return the information I want except for the current process. I'd like to know why and/or what can be done about it.